# How can i manipulate variable from another page ASP

Tags: asp.net, behind

I'm doing a little project.

I want to manipulate textbox of `Form2.aspx` from my Default.aspx

here's my code

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim stats As Form2 = New Form2()
Dim sim As Simulation = New Simulation()
Dim unique(5) As Integer
Dim gagnant(5) As Integer
Dim taux(5) As Integer
Dim tsS As DateTime = New DateTime()
Dim tsF As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan()

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Public Sub Simuler_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Prise du temps pour le calcul du temps de l'Exécution
    tsS = DateTime.Now


    'Générer aléatoirement le billet Gagnant
    unique = sim.GenerateGagnant()

    'Afficher les numéros du billet gagnant
    stats.numG1.Text = unique(0).ToString()
    stats.numG2.Text = unique(1).ToString()
    stats.numG3.Text = unique(2).ToString()
    stats.numG4.Text = unique(3).ToString()
    stats.numG5.Text = unique(4).ToString()
    stats.numG6.Text = unique(5).ToString()

    'Générer les billets des acheteurs
    Dim nbBillet As Integer = sim.GenerateBillet(Integer.Parse(tbX.Text), Integer.Parse(tbY.Text), Integer.Parse(tbS.Text))

    'Comparer les billets des acheteurs au billet gagnant et afficher les résultats
    gagnant = sim.comparer()

    'Prendre en mémoire les taux (%) en entrée
    taux(0) = Integer.Parse(tbP1.Text)
    taux(1) = Integer.Parse(tbP2.Text)
    taux(2) = Integer.Parse(tbP3.Text)
    taux(3) = Integer.Parse(tbP4.Text)
    taux(4) = Integer.Parse(tbP5.Text)
    taux(5) = Integer.Parse(tbP6.Text)

    'Récupérer l'historique du fichier et l'afficher

    Dim s As String = sim.lireFic()
    'historique.rtbHisto.Text = s

    'Récupérer le prix unitaire des billets en entrée
    Dim prix As Integer = Integer.Parse(tbPrix.Text)
    'Calcul des gains bruts de la Loto et les afficher
    Dim gains As Integer = prix * nbBillet
    stats.tbGains.Text = gains.ToString()

    'Calcul et affichage en $ des remises pour chaque catégorie 
    'taux * les gains total * le nb de gagnant dans la catégorie
    stats.tbA1.Text = (taux(0) / 100) * gains
    stats.tbA2.Text = (taux(1) / 100) * gains
    stats.tbA3.Text = (taux(2) / 100) * gains
    stats.tbA4.Text = (taux(3) / 100) * gains
    stats.tbA5.Text = (taux(4) / 100) * gains
    stats.tbA6.Text = (taux(5) / 100) * gains

    'Calcul des pertes de la LOTO
    Dim pertes As Integer = calcul(gains)

    'Calcul du profit NET
    stats.tbPertes.Text = pertes.ToString()
    stats.tbNet.Text = Integer.Parse(stats.tbGains.Text) - pertes

    'Fin de l'exécution et affichage de l'intervale dans la fenetre STATS
    tsF = DateTime.Now.Subtract(tsS)
    historique.tbTime.Text = tsF.Seconds & "." & tsF.Milliseconds
End Sub
```

End Class

in my Form2 behind .. there is only the pageLoad but in the aspx there is textbox `numG1 to numG5`

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Form2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Loto6_49_ASP.Form2" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Résultats</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
               <asp:TextBox ID="numG1" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>

               <asp:TextBox ID="numG2" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>

               <asp:TextBox ID="numG3" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>

               <asp:TextBox ID="numG4" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>

               <asp:TextBox ID="numG5" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>


               <asp:TextBox ID="numG6" runat="server" Width="42px"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form, from "Form2.aspx" to "Default.aspx" than you have it in the request ("Get" or "POST").

If not, you can write public property for each input you want to be editable from outside the page or pass the values by session, querystring, cache etc...

Answer (score 0):

what do u mean by manipulation here?please more clarification

you can use a `session` to store the value of textbox to do what you want on other pages.